# Way of finding remaining numbers of a list uniquely

Tags: number-theory, functions

I have a list of integers, $1,2,3...n$. I  sequentially scratch out a number, at random,  on each pass. I want a way of finding which numbers are left, without actually checking the list, after each pass (Something like a function of the numbers of the list, the value of which I can use to guess the numbers remaining). Is there a way to do this?

P.S. I don't really know the appropriate tags for this, so I have just given it two random. If there is some field which can answer this, please comment/ edit to add the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let $p_k$ represent the $k$th prime, with $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 5, \ldots$.  Then if numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ are remaining, the function value would be $Q = p_{a_1} p_{a_2} p_{a_3}, \ldots$.  Factor $Q$ and you can determine which numbers are left on the list.

Comment: This seems good, for small lists. Larger lists can be cumbursome

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan: If you want to disqualify a method because of this constraint, you should put the constraint in the original post.

Comment: Keep in mind that the factorization isn't difficult, because you're not searching arbitrarily.  You know what the original number was, and how it was factored.

Comment: Makes sense.. cool

Answer (score 0):

You could create a polynomial $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}x^{i-1}$, where $a_i$ is $1$ if $i$ is in list and $0$ if not. Then $f(2)$ interpreted as a bit string shows which items are in list.